# JQuery Escaping HTML for Preview

Tags: jquery, html, encoding

I am making a very simple preview window in JQuery using just an ordered list. I am worried the user will type in < or > and accidentally mess up the code for the page or do some sort of XSS. How can I encode special chars using Javascript to handle this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you use

```
$(yourselector).text("<h1>Your text String</h1>");
```

then jQuery will display the actual text including the special chars. If you use

```
$(yourselector).html("<h1>Your text String</h1>");
```

then the HTML special chars will be interpreted when displayed.

I assume here that you want to display the text that your user enters between the list tags.

Comment: In my case I'm making a list so I currently have something like this:
$(selector).html('<li>' + $(this).val() + '</li>') -- how would I convert this to your method?

Comment: $(Your UL selector).append('<li id="someid"></li>'); adds the li to the list and $("#someid").text($(this).val()); will then add the text to the new li. You will need to use a variable as the li's id.

Comment: $(ul selector).append('<li />').text(...) -- would this work instead or does append() return the parent instead of the created element?

Comment: append() returns the parent so as far as I can tell you need use the two statements. I don't know if anyone else could suggest a way to do it all in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could also [.wrap](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap) the element in a [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_pre.asp) tag.

```
$("#selector").wrap("<pre></pre>");
```

Comment: This might not the best idea for XSS prevention though, now that I think about it. Someone could start the input off with </pre> and end it with <pre> then inject whatever code they wanted in the center. Converting to .text() is more than likely the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the escaped value in a variable, rather than rendering it to the page, you could also try:

```
$('<div></div>').text(str).html()
```